# listview android setonitemclick makes force close

Tags: java, android

this my code as follows

```
private ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        addItemsOnlistv1();

    }


    public void addItemsOnlistv1() {

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Option 1");
        list.add("Option 2");

        final int listsize = list.size() - 1;
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list){

                 };

        listview.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        listview.setSelection(listsize); 

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                  if (listview.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Option 1")){

                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Option 1 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                  if (listview.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Option 2")){

                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Option 2 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
              }

            });

      }
```

but when i select the option my app force close ,anyone can figure it out what is wrong with the code i tried to include list directly in java not using any xml or anything support ?

This is what my logcat shows in red when click option

> 03-31 14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-31 14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 03-31 14:38:56.579:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23480):  at
>   zzz.zzz.zzz.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:51) 03-31
>   14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):    at
>   android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
>   03-31 14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
>   03-31 14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3071)
>   03-31 14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3971) 03-31
>   14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 03-31
>   14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 03-31
>   14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-31 14:38:56.579:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23480):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960) 03-31
>   14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-31
>   14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-31 14:38:56.579:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23480):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>   03-31 14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 03-31
>   14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):    at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 03-31
>   14:38:56.579: E/AndroidRuntime(23480):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: share your logcat error

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Seems like `listview.getSelectedItem().toString()` is null

Comment: i added error from logcat there is nothing like caused by which i almost check everytime

Comment: @androidstarter post line at `MainActivity.java:51`

Comment: @Piyush Kukadiya i removed if statements and no force close but now how can i know which option is selected to perform certain tasks can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this from

```
listview.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Option 1")
```

to

```
list.get(position).toString().equals("Option 1")
```